# sort pdf invoice by sku ascending

Tags: invoice

Currently in PDF invoices, the items are being sorted by the sequences when they are added into the cart.  How to sort the items in invoices by SKU”?

Answer (score 0):

You should override

> getPdf()

method in this file.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

Add function in this file

```
function sortBySku($items) {
    $AllItems = [];

    foreach ($items as $tempItem) {
        $AllItems[$tempItem->getSku()][$tempItem->getName()] = $tempItem;
    }

    $returnItems = [];
    ksort($AllItems);
    foreach ($AllItems as $tempItem) {
        foreach ($tempItem as $it) {
            $returnItems[] = $it;
        }
    }

    return $returnItems;
}
```

and change this line(:158)

```
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item)
```

replace

```
foreach (sortBySku($invoice->getAllItems()) as $item)
```